# Array of pointers to 2D arrays, reads incorrect values

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I need some help with accessing a 2D array with pointers.

I have 8 global char arrays declared like this:

```
char s1[4][16], s2[4][16], ... , s8[4][16];
```

Their values are set later in main function.

I have an array of 8 pointers to these arrays,

```
char (*s[8])[4][16];
```

Each pointer in this array is assigned like this:

```
s[0] = &s1;
s[1] = &s2;
..
..
s[7] = &s3;
```

Now to access elements of s1,
I do `*s[0][i][j]`, however I do not get the same values as those of `s1`. Same is the case for `s2`, `s3` etc.

Can someone please tell what is going wrong?

Comment: You forgot the parentheses, so the grouping is wrong.  Remember, declarators have the same syntax as the expressions in which you access the variable, so if the declarator needs parentheses, then so does the expression that accesses the variable.

Comment: An alternative would be `char (*s[8])[16];  s[0] = s1;` and so on, and then you would access the elements as `s[0][i][j]`.

Comment: @M.M Can you please explain why is normal indexing possible that way without using pointers?

Comment: @zorro all "array indexing" uses pointers. `x[y]` means `*(x+y)`. In your actual solution you could write `(*s[0])[i][j]` as `s[0][0][i][j]` if you want. My suggestion is to take out the second of the four dimensions because it only has size 1 (i.e. in array notation you will always have `[0]` as the second of the four indices)

Comment: @M.M So when you declare the array as `char (*s[8])[16]`, why is it `s[0] = s1` and not  `s[0] = &s1` ?

Comment: @zorro `&s1` has type `char (*)[4][16]` which is not compatible with `char (*)[16]`. However `s1` after decay has type `char (*)[16]`.

Comment: @M.M Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Index operator `[]` have higher precedence than indirect operator `*`, so you have to use parenthesis to dereference the pointer to the array.

Try doing `(*s[0])[i][j]`.

Comment: Wow. Never thought about it. Thank you so much.